# Extract the type from an anonymous generic function's expected argument

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I'm kind of new to TypeScript (JavaScript was my first language and I've been programming in it for years, I just haven't used TypeScript) and I was trying to write a small functional TypeScript library which handles everything by chaining class calls and returning `this`.

My problem is that I have a function named `changeValue`, which takes a function, passes it the class's current value, and takes whatever it returns and sets the current value to that. I tried to write some testing code to pass the function a `number` or a `bigint`, depending on what the function should take: some operators are only available with `number`, but not `bigint` (like `>>>`).

My attempt (which doesn't allow me to see the information I need):

```js
declare type numbery = number | bigint;

class FunctionalNumber<numbery> extends Functional<bigint> {
  // Functional is a class which has all the basic things required to use it functionally

  // ...snip...
  tap(f: <T extends numbery>(v: T) => T) {
    // Somehow find out if `f' uses a number or a bigint here
    // `typeof v` doesn't work (name not found), `typeof T` doesn't work (something with a type)

    f(this.bigintValue /* the bigint value of the current object, more helpful to use a bigint to provide overflow */ as T);
    // ^ Something like this
  }
}
```

Is this possible in TypeScript? I don't need to do this, but it would be a help to the user (I'll eventually publish this if it doesn't get abandoned or spaghettified) if they can choose to use a `number` or a `bigint`; I personally would rather type my numbers straight up instead of having to suffix them with a n.

Comment: TypeScript's type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when it is compiled to JavaScript, which is what ends up running at runtime.  So there's nothing about `f` at runtime that will know about what TypeScript thought its argument type would be.  A more fruitful way to think of your problem is: 1) "How would I do this in pure JavaScript?", and then 2) "How can I give typings to that JavaScript"?  If you edit your example code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE, I can probably write up an answer.

Comment: For example, it's possible that a solution could look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Ymp0Mm).  Would you like me to write that up as an answer?

Comment: The first solution works fine; can I put some kind of private type declaration before the function and get rid of it later? I just don't want it to be accessible to anyone who wants to use it and it seems I can't put a namespace inside a class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand which parts of this you want to hide from "anyone who wants to use it" or what your use case is.  Anyway, exposing/hiding type declarations to/from external users is sort of an orthogonal concern, isn't it?  Does it really apply to the question or is it a separate follow-up question?

Comment: Well, I guess I don't want to expose the types to users because of "cleanliness" or something, it's like using `private` to prevent users from using it: of course they _could_ use it, but you don't want them to.

Comment: I'm hoping you can tell me either "the issue of type exposure is of secondary concern to me and you should post your solution as an answer without trying to address this" or "this issue of type exposure is important for my use case and I will only consider answers that deal appropriately with it".  Note that in the second case you should update your question with enough details of the use case so that a potential answer can be tested against it.  Right now I still don't understand exactly *which* parts of the code are meant to be hidden/private and which are meant to be exposed.

Comment: I think I would need to apply the second; I don't want to expose the types. It's not super-duper important, but I think exposing it would be worse than not exposing it...? Should I just delete most / all of my question and rewrite it so it focuses more towards "I have this solution to my earlier question; how do I make it not exposed to the user"? I think I might as well just make a new question at that point.

Comment: If you feel that the solution works for your question as asked, but you have a followup issue about handling who can see what types, then it sounds like the first option, not the second.  Once you have an answer to your question about distinguishing functions that operate on `bigint` vs functions that operate on `number`, you can open a new question about type exposure which may or may not need to reference anything about `bigint` or `number` since a [mcve] for type exposure does not necessarily involve those.  I think I'm going to write up the original answer and see what happens ‍♂️